# How to Pass complex Objects into the FXML via Namespace and FXMLLoader?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a custom Component.

```java
public class CustomBtn extends Button{

      private ComplexObject properties;

      public void setProperties(ComplexObject properties){
           this.properties = properties;
      }

      public ComplexObject getProperties(){
           return properties
      }
}

public class ComplexObject {
    String x = "hello";
    int y = 42;
}
```

And in the FXML I could access the component via

```xml
<Pane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <children>
     <CustomBtn text="hello">
       <properties>
       <!-- here I want to pass the object via namespace placeholder but I don't know how -->
       <properties>
     </CustomBtn>
  </children>
</Pane>
```

And I want to pass a object into the Properties via FXML loader.

```java
public class SampleAppLauncher extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){

        URL val = FXView.class.getClassLoader().getResource("sample.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(val);
        
        Map<String, Object> ns = getNameSpace();
        ComplexObject property = new ComplexObject();
        property.x = "Bye bye";
        property.y = 420;
        // Here is the Object I want to pass
        ns.put("props", property);
        Pane p = loader.load(); 
        Scene s = new Scene(p);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
```

I want to pass the Parameter with

> ${} Anotation

like:

```xml
<Pane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <children>
     <CustomBtn text="hello">
       <properties>
          ${props}
       <properties>
     </CustomBtn>
  </children>
</Pane>
```

is that possible?

I know I could just use "code behind" methods like @FXMl and then set after it is loaded. But I want to understand which objects are "passable" to the Namespace and how do I configure "more complex" Objects of custom Components in FXML.
Is the "the Namespace Map is only for "primitive values"?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues:

```
public class CustomBtn extends Button{

    ...    

    public ComplexObject getProperties(){
        return properties
    }
}
```

Since `Node` already contains a method `getProperties` with the same number of arguments and the type returned from your method is not assignment compatible to the return type of `Node.getProperties`, you are not allowed to override the method with the one in your class. You need to choose a different name for your property.

```
Map<String, Object> ns = getNameSpace();
```

The method is named `getNamespace` and it's part of `FXMLLoader`, not `Application`. You need to change this line to

```
Map<String, Object> ns = loader.getNamespace();
```

Let's change the name of your property to `myProperty`:

```
public class CustomBtn extends Button{

      ...

      public void setMyProperty(ComplexObject properties){
           ....
      }

      public ComplexObject getMyProperty(){
           ...
      }
}
```

You can use `<fx:reference>` to insert the property via fxml:

```xml
 <CustomBtn text="hello">
   <myProperty>
     <fx:reference source="props"/>
   <myProperty>
 </CustomBtn>
```

Alternatively use an attribute starting with `$`:

```xml
 <CustomBtn text="hello" myProperty="$props" />
```